# Keep getting the same answer when writing a recursive function

Tags: c

Note: I'm fairly new to C programming so I don't know everything just yet.

So I'm working on this assignment for my programming class where I have to write a recursive function count_digits( ) that counts all the digits in a string. I wrote the program and got it to compile but when I type in a number, it always gives me the same answer.

This is what my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int count_digits(int num)
{
    static int count=0;
    if(num>0)
    {
        count++;
        count_digits(num/10);
    }
    else
    {
        return count;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    int count=0;

    printf("Enter any number:");
    scanf("%d",&number);

    count=count_digits(number);
    printf("\nTotal digits in [%d] are: %d\n",number,count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `if` branch doesn't return anything, so your function has *undefined behavior*

Comment: And what is the 'same answer' that you always get?

Comment: Note that your count() method will only work once until you reload the program because you can't reset the static count between usages. There are better ways to do this than using a static variable or recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Your non void function returns nothing if `num` is greater than zero. The compiler should warn you about not returning value. The fix:

```
return count_digits(num/10);
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things to consider:
What happens if you call your function count_digit() more than one time in the program?
What if you enter 0, 10, 100 as number?

Perhaps you should rethink using a static variable here.
Also for debugging, insert some printfs (or use the debugger) in count_digit() to check how your function behaves.

Comment: This should be better a comment, and not a response, as these are only sugestions to track the problem more.